# Entity Freamework Core only fills navigation property for first item

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a table for shop products, and a view that gathers all attributes of product:

```
    public class Product
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<ProductAttribute> ProductAttributes { get; set; }
        //... more fields
    }

    public class ProductAttribute
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        //... more fields
    }
```

I register them like this:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<ProductAttribute>()
        .ToView("ProductAttributes");

    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
        .HasMany(x => x.ProductAttributes)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.ProductId);
```

I then query Products with Attributes included

```
    _dbContext.Products.Include(x => x.ProductAttributes)
```

This results with only first returned item to have ProductAttributes populated. It does not matter how I filter or order data, always only first item works as expected. If I test query generated by `ToQueryString()` All values in result have properly filled joins.

What should I do to have navigation properties of all values filled?

Comment: Anything unusual in the database view serving product attributes? For instance, `Id` not being unique in the returned result set?

Comment: It's good to show reduced code, but OTOH it may hide too much. Is there any code in the class constructors? Also, it would help to see the view definition. What happens if you only query `ProductAttribute`s?

Comment: You are right, the provided information was not enough. Next time I will do better. Anyway, @IvanStoev your hunch was spot on, `Id` was indeed not unique. I managed to solve it by defining composite key form both `Id` and `ProductId` using HasKey. Would you like to make it as an answer so that i could accept it?

Comment: Glad it helped. But that was just a wild guess, feel free to provide and accept a self answer for the future readers, I'll be happy to UV it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was caused by Key field in `ProductAttribute` not being unique.

Since in my case there was no way to have a unique key, I solved it by defining composite key for that model.

I removed `[Key]` from `ProductAttribute` class and defined it in model builder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductAttribute>()
    .ToView("ProductAttributes")
    .HasKey(nameof(ProductAttribute.Id), nameof(ProductAttribute.ProductId));
```